# Populate an Intune/MS Endpoint Manager Device Group based on a User Group

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, mdm, intune

How can you create a device group, based on membership in a user group in Azure/Intune/MS Endpoint Manager?

Ideally, there should be a means of using a dynamic group query in Azure/Intune/MS Endpoint Manager to populate a device group based on a user group.  Unfortunately, the fields needed to do this do not appear to be exposed to the group dynamic membership query environment/engine.  I've submitted the feature request to MS, but in the interim was looking for another pathway to solve this need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this functionality does not exist as of yet.  I've submitted the feature request to MS, but in the interim developed a Powershell Script to solve this need, and wanted to share it as I found no posting of such a script anywhere I searched.  It could be tailored for other uses, and could have other functionality added, but for now it's a good start for someone needing a base for this type of need (IE the folks in accounting need App XYZ available on their device with this specific configuration).

I hope this helps others, and feel free to post updated versions with expanded capabilities that you extend from what I'm posting.  Below is also a link to the feature request that I've submitted for this to be available within the dynamic membership query functionality within Azure AD/MS Endpoint Manager/Intune, as upvoting there would be very helpful to get this ultimately solved the right way, natively within Azure/MSEM/Intune.

https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/75f632df-92b7-ed11-a81b-002248519701

```
#This could be run via automation to update the group membership at an interval to maintain groups    
#Connect to mggraph beta environment with priviledges.  This may work with read access for User and Directory.
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.ReadWrite.All", "Directory.ReadWrite.All", "DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperations.All"
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"

#Get the User members of this group
#Replace the user group id below with your user group id
$grpMembers = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId "12345ab1-a1ab-123a-a123-123a4567b890" -All | Where {$_}
$grpUsers = ($grpMembers.AdditionalProperties).userPrincipalName

#Get list of devices for users in group
$uDevices = $grpUsers | ForEach-Object {Get-MgUserRegisteredDevice -UserId $_}

#Get list of personal devices from the full list of devices for the users in group
$pDevices = $uDevices.AdditionalProperties | Where {$_.deviceOwnership -eq "Personal"} 

#There is a bug in what ID is returned or used with different mggraph commands so we need to translate
#the ID returned above to the ID needed for adding device group membership.  
#Fixing this is a breaking change, so will not be fixed until a major version update of MgGraph environment  
#At that time, this step of translating the ID returned will/can be removed

#Translate DeviceId returned from Get-MgUserRegisteredDevice to the DeviceID needed to add devices to device group
$gDevices = $pDevices.deviceId | ForEach-Object {get-mgdevice -Filter "DeviceId eq '$($_)'"}

#Get current device group membership
#Replace the group ID below with your device group ID.
$eDevices = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId "a123456b-12ab-12a3-abc1-123abcd34efg" -All

If($eDevices -ne $null){ #If the group isn't empty...
#Compare devices from the existing devices in the group with the current devices that should be in the group
$cDevices = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $eDevices.Id -DifferenceObject $gDevices.Id -IncludeEqual

#Based on comparison flag of results for each object in existing or current devices lists, do nothing, add new devices, or remove non-current devices
$cDevices | ForEach-Object {If ($($_.SideIndicator) -eq "==") {Write-Host "No change for $($_.InputObject)"}}
#Replace the group ID below with your device group ID.
$cDevices | ForEach-Object {If ($($_.SideIndicator) -eq "=>") { New-MgGroupMember -GroupId "a123456b-12ab-12a3-abc1-123abcd34efg" -DirectoryObjectId $($_.InputObject); Write-Host "Added $($_.InputObject)"}}
#Replace the group ID below with your device group ID.
$cDevices | ForEach-Object {If ($($_.SideIndicator) -eq "<=") { Remove-MgGroupMemberByRef -GroupId "a123456b-12ab-12a3-abc1-123abcd34efg" -DirectoryObjectId $($_.InputObject); Write-Host "Removed $($_.InputObject)"}}

} Else {
    #Add all devices for users to the empty group
    #Replace the group ID below with your device group ID.
    $gDevices | ForEach-Object {New-MgGroupMember -GroupId "a123456b-12ab-12a3-abc1-123abcd34efg" -DirectoryObjectId $($_.Id); Write-Host "Added $($_.Id)"}
}
```